# Remove specific string at the end position of each row from dataframe(csv)

Tags: r

I am trying to clean a set of data which is in csv format. After loading data into R, i need to replace and also remove some characters from the it. Below is an example. Ideally i want to

1. replace the **St** at the end of each -> Street
2. in cases where there are **St St.**
3. i need to remove St and replace St. with just Street.

I tried to use this code

```
sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St.", replacement = " ") and later

gsub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St.", replacement = " ") to remove the St. at the end of each row but this also remove some other occurrences of St and the next character 


3   James St.

4   Glover Road St.

5   Jubilee Estate. St.

7   Fed Housing Estate St.

8   River State School St.

9   Brown  State Veterinary Clinic. St.

11  Saw Mill St.

12  Dyke St St.

13  Governor Rd St.
```

Comment: `gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)`. So, what part is not working?

Comment: @Gopala with my code it removes the St. at the end of the cell but also Sta eg in Brown  State Veterinary Clinic. St. and i only want to remove only the ST. at the end.

Comment: You might want to look into `stringr` or `stringi` packages which have some straight forward functions for such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing a lot of close answers but I'm not seeing any that address the second problem he's having such as replacing "St St." with "Street"; e.g., "Dyke St St."

`sub`, as stated in the documentation:

> The two *sub functions differ only in that sub replaces only the first occurrence of a pattern

So, just using "St\\." as the pattern match is incorrect.

OP needs to match a *possible* pattern of "St St." and I'll further assume that it could even be "St. St." or "St. St".

Assuming OP is using a simple list:

```
x = c("James St.", "Glover Road St.", "Jubilee Estate. St.", 
    "Fed Housing Estate St.", "River State School St St.", 
    "Brown State Vet Clinic. St. St.", "Dyke St St.")`
```

> [1] "James St."                       "Glover Road St."
>   [3] "Jubilee Estate. St."             "Fed Housing Estate St."
>   [5] "River State School St St."       "Brown State Vet Clinic. St. St."
>   [7] "Dyke St St."

Then the following will replace the possible combinations mentioned above with "Street", as requested:

```
y <- sub(x, pattern = "[ St\\.]*$", replacement = " Street")
```

> [1] "James Street"                  "Glover Road Street"
>   [3] "Jubilee Estate Street"         "Fed Housing Estate Street"
>   [5] "River State School Street"     "Brown State Vet Clinic Street"
>   [7] "Dyke Street"

**Edit:**

To answer OP's question below in regard to replacing one substr of **St.** with **Saint** and another with **Street**, I was looking for a way to be able to match similar expressions to return different values but at this point I haven't been able to find it. I suspect `regmatches` can do this but it's something I'll have to fiddle with later.

A simple way to accomplish what you're wanting - let's assume:

`x <- c("St. Mary St St.", "River State School St St.", "Dyke St. St")`

> [1] "Saint Mary St St."         "River State School St St."
>   [3] "Dyke St. St"

So you want x[1] to be **Saint Mary Street**, x[2] to be **River State School Street** and x[3] to be **Dyke Street**. I would want to resolve the **Saint** issue first by assigning `sub()` to `y` like:

`y <- sub(x, pattern = "^St\\.", replacement = "Saint")`

> [1] "Saint Mary Street"         "River State School Street"
>   [3] "Dyke Street"

To resolve the St's as the end, we can use the same resolution as I posted *except* notice now I'm not using `x` as my input vector but isntead the `y` I just made:

`y <- sub(y, pattern = "[ St\\.]*$", replacement = " Street")`

And that should take care of it. Now, I don't know if this is the most efficient way. And if you're dataset is rather large this may run slow. If I find a better solution I will post it (provided no one else beats me).

Comment: your answer works perfectly. It addressed the problem of removing and replacing the St St. at the end of the string. But I realized the occurrence of St. in some cases at the beginning of some strings ie St. Mary St St. This i need to change to Saint Mary Street  ( i can see it with grep(pattern = "^St\\.", x = )). I have tried different code combinations but could not replace it from St to Saint. I could transfer it to spreadsheet but i would prefer preparing and analyzing everything in R

Comment: @mapperx, I've posted an update to my original. It's important to realize when using `grep` you're asking for the indices of the dataframe to which the pattern is found to be returned, not to replace the input vector. In order to *substitute* a substring with another substring, you'll want `sub()` or `gsub()`; the former only replaces the first found occurrence and the latter replaces all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regular expression here.

```
sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St.", replacement = " ", fixed=T)
```

The `fixed` argument means that you want to replace this exact character, not matches of a regular expression.

Comment: I was able to achieve the result in 2 steps and with two scripts

evo1 <- sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St", replacement = "Street", fixed=T) this to replace the St with Street
then
evo2 <- sub(x = evo1, pattern = "St\\.", replacement = " ") to remove the St.
Then i realized that there is the possibility to have a name like St. John or St. Micheal. I dont want to remove the St that occurs at the beginning of the line. Is it possible to limit the removal and replacement to the end location.

Comment: I do think that @Tim Trice's solution addresses your issue. In this specific case, you would then need to use a regular expression, and to use `$` to specify that you only want to match a sequence at the end (as also demonstrated in @dmontaner's solution). It would give something like `sub(x=evostreet, pattern="St\\.$", replacement="Street", fixed=F)`. But to also address your second problem (consecutive occurrences of "St." at the end of your string), I really believe that @Tim Trice's solution is the best.

Comment: Tim Trice solution addressed it perfectly removing and replacing the St St. at the end of the string with Street. But I realized the occurrence of St. in some cases at the beginning of some strings ie St. Mary St St. This i need to change to Saint Mary Street  ( i can see it with grep(pattern = "^St\\.", x = )). I have tried different code combinations but could not replace it from St to Saint. I could transfer it to spreadsheet but i would prefer preparing and analyzing everything in R

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that the '.' character in the regular expression world means "any single character". So to match literally in R you should write

```
sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St\\.", replacement = " ")
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me replace the St. at the end to Street. Now i need to remove the St  like in 

12 Dyke St Street

Comment: I was able to achieve the result in 2 steps and with two scripts

evo1 <- sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St", replacement = "Street", fixed=T) this to replace the St with Street
then
evo2 <- sub(x = evo1, pattern = "St\\.", replacement = " ") to remove the St.
Then i realized that there is the possibility to have a name like St. John or St. Micheal. I dont want to remove the St that occurs at the beginning of the line. Is it possible to limit the removal and replacement to the end location.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to "comment" the dot... otherwise it means anything after St and that is why some other parts of your text are eliminated.

```
sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St\\.", replacement = " ")
```

You can add $ at the end if you want to remove the tag apearing just at the end of the text.

```
sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St\\.$", replacement = " ")
```

The difference between `sub` and `gsub` is that sub will deal just with the firs time your tag appears in a text. `gsub` will eliminate all if there are duplicated. In your case as you are looking for the pattern at the end of the line it should not make any difference if you use the $.

Comment: I was able to achieve the result in 2 steps and with two scripts

evo1 <- sub(x = evostreet, pattern = "St", replacement = "Street", fixed=T) this to replace the St with Street
then
evo2 <- sub(x = evo1, pattern = "St\\.", replacement = " ") to remove the St.
Then i realized that there is the possibility to have a name like St. John or St. Micheal. I dont want to remove the St that occurs at the beginning of the line. Is it possible to limit the removal and replacement to the end location.